# SQL server throwing error msg102 during Stored procedure creation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a stored procedure. The code for the creation is as shown below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AITS_Card_POS_Save
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @cardnum nvarchar(20)=null,
    @CrdTyp nvarchar(50)=null,
    @sInno int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @crtid as int
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select @crtid=crtid from creditcardtype_tbl where cardtype=@CrdTyp

    insert into CreditCard_POS_tbl(Cardnum,crtid,Slinvid) values(@cardnum,@crtid,@sInno)

Go
```

While executing it I am getting error as follows

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AITS_Card_POS_Save, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What could be the reason??

Answer (score 2):

You are missing 'End' keyword after your Insert statement.